# removing null value from the table - oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, select, union

I have the oracle table

```
Header1 | Header2 | Header 3| Header 4
--------+---------+----------+---------
abcd    | 1       | null     | null
abcd    | null    | 3        | null
abcd    | null    | null     | 2
```

Is there a query to get

```
Header1 | Header2 | Header 3| Header 4
--------+---------+----------+---------
abcd    | 1       | 3       | 2
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This

```
SELECT Header1,Max(Header2),Max(Header3),Max(Header4)
From Table1
Group By Header1
```

---

Output will be

---

```
    Header1 | Header2 | Header 3| Header 4
    --------+---------+---------+---------
    abcd    | 1       | 3       | 2
```

Comment: thanks for the answer - what if these were none numeric values?

Comment: But when it is alpha numbefic, 2 is greaster than 1000. Just FYI.